# Is there a way to generate a QR code with a custom logo in the middle in Perl?

Tags: perl, qr-code

We've been successfully using [GD::Barcode::QRcode](https://metacpan.org/pod/GD::Barcode::QRcode) to generate QR codes on the fly.

We now want to try to embed our small custom logo in every QR code we generate.

Is there a way to do that in Perl?

Comment: I am trying to locate the actual specs for this, as it doesn't look like there is a Perl implementation that can do that. https://scanova.io/blog/how-to-make-a-custom-qr-code/ is a good write-up of how this works I think, bu it isn't the actual spec or RFC.

Comment: There is an exact number of squares (percentage)  that can be covered depending on the error correction chosen, this again depends on the content amount.  It should be possible to calculate this value, and overlay your logo on the resulting barcode, since you are already using GD.

Comment: According to that link, sounds like they simply max out the error correction (`Ecc => 'H'`*), overlay the image, and hope the error correction isn't otherwise needed?  (* The article says `V`, but that's not an option for the module. And the official QR site [doesn't list `V`](https://www.qrcode.com/en/about/error_correction.html). It says `H` is the one that's ~30%.)

Comment: Following [web page](http://vecg.cs.ucl.ac.uk/Projects/SmartGeometry/halftone_QR/halftoneQR_sigga13.html) demonstrates _Halftone QR codes_ with description of _system pipeline_ how this algorithm can be implemented.